# Verify if SQLServer installation needs reboot

Tags: sql-server, scripting, installation

I managed to install SQL server on a clean machine with scripts.

But sometimes the scripts won't work because the machine needs a reboot.

**My ask:**

1.Is there any way to detect if reboot is required while installing SQLserver
2.If reboot is needed,reboot it automatically

Comment: Sorry  I mean MS SQL Server

Comment: you mean to say `you  are trying to automate sql server installation through cmd line and looking for a method to reboot`

Comment: Yes. Since in my scripts, the installation always fails while a reboot is needed. I am looking for a way that can reboot if a reboot is needed during the install verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In summary ,When a reboot is needed,the value is logged in Registry at below places..

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired

HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\RebootPending

HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager
```

Before installing ,you can run below powershell script..

```
#Adapted from https://gist.github.com/altrive/5329377
#Based on <http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-PendingReboot-Query-bdb79542>
function Test-PendingReboot
{
 if (Get-ChildItem "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\RebootPending" -EA Ignore) { return $true }
 if (Get-Item "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\Auto Update\RebootRequired" -EA Ignore) { return $true }
 if (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager" -Name PendingFileRenameOperations -EA Ignore) { return $true }
 try { 
   $util = [wmiclass]"\\.\root\ccm\clientsdk:CCM_ClientUtilities"
   $status = $util.DetermineIfRebootPending()
   if(($status -ne $null) -and $status.RebootPending){
     return $true
   }
 }catch{}

 return $false
}
```

if the above function returns true ,you can run below command..

```
Restart-Computer -ComputerName "Server01", "Server02", "localhost"
```

Server* stands for some names servers and localhost stands for local computer

**References:**
http://ilovepowershell.com/2015/09/10/how-to-check-if-a-server-needs-a-reboot/

Comment: Great! I was thinking a reboot when a reboot detect during the installation progress. Never thought of reboot before everything. This should work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Or lunch the install from command line (cmd) like so

`C:\Users\username\Downloads\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe /SKIPRULES=RebootRequiredCheck /ACTION=Install`

fist is the address where the setup exe is located and second the parameters to skip reboot check